# Regular Expression with XML in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a xml like below:

```
<example id='1'>
   <val name='test1'/>
</example>
<example id='2' command='delete'>
   <val name='test2'/>
</example>
<example id='3'>
   <val name='test3'/>
</example>
```

I'm trying to use regular expressions within notepad++ to delete all *example* items with *commands='delete'* so that in the above example, test1 and test3 should be remaining.

I can easily do ones with no values like below but it's just the ones with values.

```
 <example id='1' command='delete' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<example[^>]+command='delete'[^>]*>.*?<\/example>
```

(enable "dot matches newline")

and replace with the empty string.

https://regex101.com/r/e8E7cB/1

Answer (score 0):

Please use Search mode: "Regular expression" with ". matches newline"

```
<example.[^>]*command='delete'.*?</example>
```